# Implemented RWBlurPopover cant select value from tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have integrated [RWBlurPopover](https://github.com/eternityz/RWBlurPopover). I have added tableview inside Popover. Data is showing fine in tableview but when i am selecting any row didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not calling.

I have implemented delegate and data source methods
I guess i can find code inside RWBlurpopover that is disabling touch on tableview.
Because all i am doing same as i have done in other Table View and it works file.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So RWBlurPopover, by default, dismisses on tap. To change that behaviour, you should go to RWBlurPopover.m and remove or comment out these lines:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss)];
[self.popoverView.blurView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```